# Symfony2 - Query Builder LIKE null values

Tags: symfony, null, doctrine, query-builder

I'm trying to build a dynamic query in response to a custom search from users. I have an issue: when I'm building the query, I don't have the results because the SELECT LIKE column comparison doesn't work with NULL values. How can I work around this issue, considering that query is dynamically built? So, users can give values or not to search criteria...

This is my code:

```
$qb->add('select', 'f')
   ->add('from', 'Bundle:Object f')
   ->add('where', $qb->expr()->andx(
            $qb->expr()->like('f.c1',':c1'),
            $qb->expr()->like('f.c2',':c2'),
            $qb->expr()->like('f.c3',':c3')))
   ->add('orderBy', 'f.nnumCatalogo ASC');
if ($data->getField1() != null) {
  $isField1 = true;
}
if ($data->getField2() != null) {
  $isField2 = true;
}
if ($data->getField3() != null) {
  $isField3 = true;
}
if ($isField1) {
  $qb->setParameter('c1', $data->getField1());
} else {
  $qb->setParameter('c1', '%');
}
if ($isField2) {
  $qb->setParameter('c2', $data->getField2());
} else {
  $qb->setParameter('c2', '%');
}
if ($isField3) {
  $qb->setParameter('c3', $data->getField3());
} else {
  $qb->setParameter('c3', '%');
}
```

With this code I have no results becuase of NULL values in some columns not selected with LIKE '%' (mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$qb->add('select', 'f')->add('from', 'Bundle:Object f');
if ($data->getField1() != null) {
    $qb->andWhere('f.c1 like :c1')
    ->setParameter('c1', $data->getField1());
}
if ($data->getField2() != null) {
    $qb->andWhere('f.c2 like :c2')
    ->setParameter('c2', $data->getField2());
}
if ($data->getField3() != null) {
    $qb->andWhere('f.c3 like :c3')
    ->setParameter('c3', $data->getField3());
}
$qb->add('orderBy', 'f.nnumCatalogo ASC');
```